# Polymer 1.0's iron-ajax passes nothing to script

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm trying to get an iron-ajax element to submit a variable to a PHP script that can then use the variable and send back a response. I know it fires because the script does send back a response and I can pass variables back to my app. However, iron-ajax sends absolutely nothing to the script FROM the app.

I've tried a lot of different methods from SO and the official documentation, but so far nothing has yielded results. The Polymer docs are still a work in progress - I've run out of ideas. Hopefully somebody out there has been through the same thing already and knows what I'm doing wrong.

Here's what I've got so far:

**index.php**

```js
...
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
...
<div id="output"></div>

<iron-ajax 
    id="ajax" 
    url="remove.php"
    method="GET" 
    handle-as="json" 
    content-type="application/json" 
    on-response="_onResponseRetrieved">
</iron-ajax>
<div id="12345">
<!-- when this button is tapped, the ajax fires -->
<paper-button id="Remove" on-tap="_remove">Remove</paper-button>
</div>
...
</template>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
...
```

**app.js**

```js
(function(document) {
'use strict';
...
app._remove = function(e) {
  var removeID = e.srcElement.parentElement.id;
  this.$.ajax.params = '{"ID":"'+removeID+'"}';
  this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
  };

app._onResponseRetrieved = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  this.$.output = e.detail.response['output'];
  }
...
})(document);
```

**remove.php**

```js
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// I read on github that this was at one point a 
// workaround for an iron-ajax POST bug, so I'm 
// checking it here just to make sure there's nothing
// getting missed, but it turns up empty anyways, 
// just like POST and GET
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$jsonData = json_decode($json, true);

// this just counts the # of variables this script 
// received
$output['output'] = "POST:(".count($_POST).")<br>";
$output['output'] .= "GET:(".count($_GET).")<br>";
$output['output'] .= "JSON:(".count($jsonData).")";
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```js
POST:(0)
GET:(0)
JSON:(0)
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: `'{"ID":"'+removeID+'"}'` looks quite weird. Is the intention to send the string `'+removeID+'` including the quotes as part of the string?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Yes that is the intent, because the iron-ajax specs say specifically _Note: The params attribute must be double quoted JSON._  ... although I could be misunderstanding the implementation of that.

Comment: Actually re-reading your question, `removeID` is not a string... it is a variable defined just above that line. `+` is just concatenating it to the rest of the string. The end string which I believe should be getting passed would look like this: `{"ID":"12"}` (assuming removeID = 12)

Comment: This is definitively wrong. This is when you add it in markup like show in the docs https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax.  From JS it just needs to be a valid JS object. Try  `this.$.ajax.params = {"ID": removeID};` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by add it in markup? The params attribute defined in the specs - in your link - looks exactly like the params attribute I'm setting with JS. Is there some kind of JSON object that I should be setting instead?

Comment: There is a difference if you add it in the HTML part (markup) or in the JavaScript part. In HTML it's an **attribute**  you assign a string to and the element and Polymer takes care it's deserialized to an JavaScript object. In JavaScript (your example) the JavaScript VM creates a JavaScript object from your code which is assigned to the `params` **property** and passed as is (without deserialization).

Comment: If you use a POST request you should assign the object to body instead. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both POST and GET methods. I think the implementation differences include iron-ajax's **method** property and using **body** for POST vs **params** for GET... did I forget something? Does **body** also take the same JSON? I've seen examples where someone set **body** to something like **&var=val&var2=val2** but it just seemed plain wrong to me (and also didn't work)

Comment: Looks like www-form-urlencoded (see docs for the `body` property) You can pass different formats and iron-ajax recognizes these two.

Comment: I was half way through switching to www-form-urlencoded when I noticed a huge gaff on my part. I had another element in my code with the same ID as my iron-ajax block... I was likely setting params/body on the wrong element before submitting it. Thanks so much for all your help - you should write the part about formatting json properly in an answer - that was the real issue here, my own stupidity aside ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `param` property needs an object instead of a string. Create it this way instead

```
this.$.ajax.params = {"ID": removeID};
```